# Inset raster graphic position and size

Tags: plotting, rasterize

I need to rasterize a very complicate plot and superimpose this to another plot.
For example

```
g=Rasterize[Plot[Cos[2\[Pi]x],{x,0,1},Axes->None],Background->None,ImageResolution->100];
Plot[Sin[2 \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}, Background -> None,Prolog -> Inset[Graphics[g]]]
```

However this does not produce the right alignment/scaling.
Any idea how to obtain the correct behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I've realized the trick later

```
g = Rasterize[
Plot[Cos[2 \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], Background -> None, 
ImageResolution -> 100];
Plot[Sin[2 \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
Background -> None, 
Prolog -> Inset[Graphics[g], {0.5, 0}, Automatic, 1]]
```

Just matter to add the plot ranges and scale the inset!